# in play framework, how does secure.connected() work?

Tags: security, cookies, playframework

new to play,

I noticed in tutorial and online documentation that play's secure model 
uses `Security.connected()` method to get current connected user.

my question is, how does it work ? how can play know who sent the last request ?
does it use a cookie ?

if so, copying this cookie would allow me to use different computers for viewing page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Play use cookie to get the user information. The cookie itself is encrypted. Not sure if copy it to another computer allow you to view the page. But I think this is not a security leak. Say, if you have a secure word document, and you copy it to another computer, it will allow the user on that computer to view your doc.

Comment: The cookie is not encrypted, it's signed and can not be altered but it's contents is visible: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/security